LibreOffice Writer doesn't import Base query fields containing LIST()
I have a query in LibreOffice Base (Firebird) which uses the LIST() function. It works perfectly fine, but when creating a Writer document with database fields utilizing this particular query, it doesn't work. The document will show no data.
I haven't been able to find anything online about this being an issue for others. I utilize the database fields in other documents (from the same database even) and all other instances work just fine. The LIST() function seems to be the only possible factor ruining thing here. Is there something I might be missing?

This seems off-topic for Stack Overflow, as I wouldn't consider this programming, but LIST() produces a blob sub_type text, maybe that is what's different compared to other expressions you're using. You could try casting to a varchar of sufficient size.

Tried casting the entire LIST() as VARCHAR and it doesn't help.

Very helpful, thank you. No wonder me using this for years now with little problems has actually just been a long dream.

Please give full steps to reproduce the problem, including simplified example data. I did the following and it worked as a database field in Writer: SELECT CAST( LIST( "name" ) AS VARCHAR ( 255 ) ) "concatenated_names" FROM "Table1". I also tried removing CAST but then, although it still works in Base, it didn't work in Writer.

By the way, SQL and database are completely on-topic for StackOverflow, so I was surprised to see the earlier comment. Also, people certainly do use Firebird, although there are some problems that I've run across, so some projects may require hsqldb 1.8 instead. Either way, to really do it right requires a split setup with for example postgresql.

@JimK It's more that using SQL in something like LibreOffice Writer, which is a word processor, and as such not something "primarily used by developers" is a bit on/at the edge of whether it's on-topic or not. If the question was about writing SQL, it would definitely be on-topic, but "this feature in Writer that allows me to get data from a database" is IMHO not.
